# What is the easiest way to allow users of my Django site to search for posts that I've written on the site?

Tags: django

I don't want to write a search algorithm and I suspect that there must be a library or script to do this. Are there any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have created something like blog application:

```
object_list = Post.objects.all()
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    object_list = object_list.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(content__icontains=query)
    ).distinct()
```

Here `title` and `content` are attributes of model `Post`. Change them accordingly.

Use `q` to get value from search `form` in `template`.